# Chrome Extension: Do messages sent to tabs can be listen by any chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sandbox

As explained there https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging,
when sending a message using the following code

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, <message>);
```

it can be only received by the backgound script of the same extension.

--

But what about messages sent to tabs ?
Does message sent using the following code

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, message, callback);
    }
});
```

can by received by contents script of any extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will be broadcast in the contexts of your own extension ID to all frames within that tab. By that I mean that every frame has its own "page" context associated with it, and one context per every extension that injected scripts in it, and they are all isolated from each other.

So only your context script(s) will receive that. In fact, it's impossible to directly message another extension's content scripts.

It's similar to calling `runtime.sendMessage` without an id: it is then assumed that you want your own extension, and it won't be sent to any other extensions.